# what is the BEST way to populate several tables with different data on one view?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am building an **iPad** app. I want to have one of the views (xib) to display several tables with different data populated into each table at run time, i.e., when the view loads I want to run a query for each table and return the query results as rows into the relevant tables. SO for tableA I would run queryA and return datasetA, tableB,queryB,datasetB and so on. How can I do this? can you give example code? I also want to be able to interact with the tables, e.g., slect a row and pass the information to another screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier way than BalaChandra's answer(that it´s correct):

I suppose your UITableViews are instance variables (or even properties). So if you have instantiated your table views like:

```
UITableView *tableViewA = [[UITableView alloc] init...];
UITableView *tableViewB = [[UITableView alloc] init...];
```

for example, you don't need setting the tag to the tableviews.
In the UITableViewDelegate/UITableViewDataSource methods you can check which tableView is with something like:

```
if (tableView == tableViewA) {
    // Do something with tableA... 
}
else if (tableView == tableViewB) {
    // Do something with tableB...
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

just create four tables and place them on the view, set the tableview delegate and datasource to self.Give each table a particular tag. In the datasource or delegate method, before performing the operations check the tag of that particular tableview and run the query related to it.
eg:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// The header for the section is the region name -- get this from the region at the section index.
if (tableView.tag ==12) {
    return @"comments:";
}
else
{
return sectiontitle;
}
}
```

where one table has tag=12 , if the tag is 12 perform the operations related to that table, otherwise operations related to other table.

Comment: OK, I will try that, sounds logical. Is this the right way of setting the delegate and datasource to self (from within the ViewController implementation file that holds the tables right?) 'mytable = [[UITableView alloc] init];
[mytable setDelegate:self]; [mytable setDataSource.self];'

Comment: you can directly assign mytable.datasoucre = self; why bothering about all that

Comment: thanks BalaChandra, can you expand on your comment?

Comment: The method you specified is also correct, i am just saying that after the table is created. you can directly assign datasource and delegate by using setter. mytable.datasource = self and mytable.delegate = self. make sure you implement them in your header file

Comment: Hi @BalaChandra, can you point me to more detailed instructions on how to follow your recommendation?

Comment: You want to run a different query when a cell from different table is selected, so in the tableview delegate and datasource methods just check to which table that cell belongs and run the appropriate query